# PkgConfig in Groovy on Quantal

Tags: ros, catkin, buildfarm, ros-groovy, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having with a job on the buildfarm.
http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-groovy-people-tracking-filter_binarydeb_quantal_i386/2/console

Probably relevant error:

```
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:319 (message):
  pkg-config tool not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Offending CMake is here: https://github.com/wg-perception/people/blob/groovy/people_tracking_filter/CMakeLists.txt

What is the proper way to check for the BFL package in Groovy that will work on the buildfarm?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191528/pkgconfig-in-groovy-on-quantal/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is perfectly fine to use `pkg-config` to resolve dependencies but if a package does so it also needs to declare that `pkg-config` is a build dependency in the package.xml file:

```
<build_depend>pkg-config</build_depend>
```

Otherwise the build farm does not know that it should be installed.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-08-29**:
Hrm. Didn't seem to take: http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-groovy-people-tracking-filter_binarydeb_precise_i386/4/console

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-08-29**:
How should it change? You haven't released a new patch release, right? The recent deb-inc still uses the same upstream code: https://github.com/OSUrobotics/people-release/blob/release/groovy/people_tracking_filter/1.0.6-1/package.xml - no pkg-config dependency in there.